# Calling the toFixed method on a number literal

Tags: javascript, tofixed

When I call the toFixed() method on a decimal number literal like so:

```
var a = 67.678.toFixed(2);
console.log(a);
```

The result works and returns 67.68

However if I call the method on an integer - I get an error

```
var b = 67.toFixed(2);
console.log(b); // causes ERROR
```

Why is this the case?

NB:

If I save the integer number to a variable - the toFixed() method does work.

```
var c = 67;
c = c.toFixed(2);
console.log(c); // returns 67.00
```

See [this jsBin](https://jsbin.com/kiyusowiwa/edit?js,console)

What is going on under the hood?

Comment: Did you tried `(67).toFixed(2)`?

Comment: well Its a language related syntax issue. when you write `xx.` if `xx` is number it assumes the next thing to appear after the `.` operator is another number. but if you enclose it in parans like `(xx).toFixed(2)` it works.

Comment: So why does the decimal number not need parenthesis?

Comment: Well I've studied the Programming Languages construction course. these are syntax related rules. when a statement appears a set of grammar rules parses  it and validates it.. Probably in the JS Grammar rules you can't put `number.function` and it return a parse/Syntax error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`var b = 67.toFixed(2);` Simply generates a parsing error as the parser can't deduce that you meant it to be a number literal followed by a property accessor (Notice that the error is on the first line, not on the `console.log(b)`)

The reason this works for `67.678.toFixed(2)` is that there's no other option. The parser can deduce without ambiguity that the number literal ended at the "8" digit and can continue parsing the next dot as a property accessor (which causes boxing into a `Number` object first BTW).

A solution is obviously simple:

```
(67).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your options include:

```
67 .toFixed(2)
(67).toFixed(2)
67..toFixed(2)
67.0.toFixed(2)
67["toFixed"](2)
```

All of these avoid the problem that the JS parser treats a dot immediately following a number as a decimal point.

Comment: Don't forget `Number.prototype.toFixed.call(67, 2)` and friends (bind, apply..)

Answer (score 1):

well Its a language related syntax issue. when you write `xx.` if `xx` is number it assumes the next thing to appear after the `.` operator is another number. but if you enclose it in parenthesis like (xx).toFixed(2) it works. what happens in a the back is an object after the parenthesis delimits the parse or when a full decimal literal is written is created and `toFixed` is called on that object.

Hope it answers our question.. :)

Comment: No, the parentheses do not "create an object". They delimit the number for purposes of parsing.

Comment: Though it may be a possibility but I guess an object is created. to link the `toFixed` method call. since the definition of the method might not be in the syntax or semantic rules of JS language

Comment: Yes, a transient object is created in order to invoke `toFixed`. However, such a object is created in any case, including `67.0.toFixed()`. You stated the parentheses create the object. That is incorrect.