# Custom Number.prototype working with variable but NOT working directly with number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have included custom Number.prototype in my JS as below:

```
Number.prototype.isBetween = function (first, last) {
   return (first < last ? this >= first && this <= last : this >= last && this <= first);
};
```

This is working as expected with below code:

```
var a = 40;
a.isBetween(10,50)
```

**Result :** 
true

But when i try to execute as below, it is throwing an error:

```
40.isBetween(10,50)
```

**Result :** 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

How to make this(40.isBetween(10,50)) work?

Comment: 40..isBetween .... the peculiarity of Number methods as distinguished from a decimal point :p or even (40).isBetween... or 40.0.isBetween...

Comment: I don't understand you? can you please explain more?

Comment: The `.` is interpreted as a decimal point. Since `40.` is the same as `40.0`, `40.isBetween` basically means `40.0isBetween`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the number in parentheses to solve this.

```
(40).isBetween(10,50)
// => true
```

Without the parentheses, there is ambiguity in the grammar that the language parser intentionally avoids by throwing an error.

For details and other solutions, see answers to this question: [Calling the toFixed method on a number literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33119274/calling-the-tofixed-method-on-a-number-literal)

Comment: Super.. :-) Worked..!!!